# Android AdBlocker - how does it work?

Tags: adblock-plus

I have just tried [this adblocker](https://adblockplus.org/android-install) app for Android, and it does seem to be working quite effectively, I tried it with some popular apps like Angry Birds and Cut the Rope.

Does anyone know how it works? I tought Android processes can't mess with one another?

Comment: You can take a look at its code if you want so. It's an open-source app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdBlock Plus uses two methods, depending on your device/setup:

For non-root on modern Android with certain devices, it changes the network proxy settings.

For root devices, it uses the classic hosts file loopback trick which alters the DNS lookup. (Instead of returning the real IP address for www.some-ad.com it returns the local loopback IP, which won't return the ad.)

Either way, at the OS network level the network settings the ad blocker changes causes Android not too request the ad at all, but instead sends back an empty or dummy HTTP response to the app.

Since the ad request was never sent, the ad networks can't track you and of course then can't show an image or ad.

See more details on the [AdBlock FAQ](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-faq).

Answer (score 1):

The [F-Droid description](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway) of [AdAway](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2190753), (which is a popular adblocker) is described as:

> An ad blocker that uses the hosts file. The hosts file contains a list
>   of mappings between hostnames and IP addresses. When an app requests
>   an ad, that request is directed to 127.0.0.1 which does nothing.

So, an adblocker redirects an app's ad requests to an IP address which produces a blank result, which prevents the ad from being visible.

Comment: but how exactly does it redirect them, does it intercept the incoming traffic, or somehow messes with the other app's processes?

Comment: As far as I know, it intercepts the incoming traffic. AdAway has a feature where you can see what traffic is coming in to your device, so that would support that hypothesis.

Comment: @1990clb apples and plums :) OP uses *AdblockPlus* (from the URL in the question). Sure that works the same? It cannot modify the `hosts` file without root permissions. As for how the hosts blocking works: It doesn't interfere with any traffic. If the client requests e.g. `www.example-spam-host.com/example.jpg`, it needs to have the IP address for that host. It first looks in the `hosts` file and, if not found there, asks the name server. So the `hosts` file has the line `www.example-spam-host.com 127.0.0.1`, which makes the client use that IP (localhost) – where nothing has the `example.jpg`.

Comment: I think it not block hosts, maybe redirect/rewrite request (like an .htaccess for a website) . More convenient is to scan app for identifiers,  organized as lists see for reference https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt .The app scans for trafic (in /out) and abort rendering of elements contained in lists. (Interesting list anyway :) )

Comment: can the users who have downvoted give some insight as to the reason why? With your suggestions I will endeavour to improve my answer.